# Subitems of different element open, besides of intended ones

Tags: html, css

I would like to know why when clicking on "Capítulo 4" also the subitems of "Capítulo 6" open?

Same happens when clicking on "Capítulo 2", subitems of "Capítulo 1" open.

[image]

**CODEPEN:**

https://codepen.io/ogonzales/pen/QWjmorP

```
  $(document).ready(function () {

    $('#sidebarCollapse').on('click', function () {
        $('#sidebar').toggleClass('active');
    });

  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The things happen here is because **you didn't use unique `id` for your `ul` items**. So whenever you trying to open/close one of your collapsable `ul` by referring them with anchor tag `href`, since their `id` is not unique both `ul`s will get open. In order to fix this, **give each `ul` a unique `id` and then refer to that unique id with your desired `a` tag**. You can read more about `id`s [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id).

For more illustration, let's say we got this `ul` element:

```html
<ul class="collapse list-unstyled" id="homeSubmenu">
  <li>
    <a href="#">Introducción</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">¿Qué es la salvación?</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">¿Se pierde la salvación?</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

and the corresponding anchor tag for this should be this one:

```html
<a href="#homeSubmenu" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false" class="dropdown-toggle">
```

There is an `id` of `homeSubmenu` which relate to `ul` element and we are referring to that with `href="#homeSubmenu"`.

So the next item should have a different `id` to work as expected, let's pick another one:

```html
<ul class="collapse list-unstyled" id="homeSubmenu2">
  <li>
    <a href="#">Introducción</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">¿Qué es la salvación?</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">¿Se pierde la salvación?</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

So the corresponding to that should be this one:

```html
<a href="#homeSubmenu2" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false" class="dropdown-toggle">
```

Here is the full working demo: [codepen.io](https://codepen.io/smalikss/pen/eYpMoyR)

Comment: but what is the code that makes them open? As far as I know, the Javascript only hides the entire sidebar. UL elemtns have this line `<ul class="collapse list-unstyled" id="pageSubmenu">`. I don't find the code that uses the id `pageSubmenu`

Comment: @OmarGonzales Actually the js code you provided, will only toggle `active` class for the `click`ed item. In order to fix your code, you should give your `ul` elements a unique id. I will share an example for you in my updated answer.

Comment: I've given another IDs, and now only the first one opens. Don't understand what code is what open the subitems. I'll get you updated anwser. Ty.

Comment: Got it, the attribute `data-toggle` works with the ID and the href. This is a Bootstrap thing, that's why I didn't find a JS code for this subitems opening. Ty.

Comment: @OmarGonzales Yea exactly.